# What is the code to concatenate 2 dataframes in this specific way with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I'm currently facing a problem, that I can't solve. I spent 6hours trying to find a solution but in the end nothing worked for me, probably because I don't use the wright things. (I'm using python, pandas, numpy)

Imagine that I have 2 dataframes that are the same except that the second one has 5 day less than the other for each cluster. Where "day" and "cluster" are column names which are sorted. And each cluster has a different number of days.

Graphically the situation is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8wDk.jpg

Now I want to merge / concatenate in such a way that my dataframe not merge depending on index. I want the first rows of the second dataframe to match the first rows of the first dataframe. Consequently it will induce NA values for the 5 last rows of the second dataframe in the merged one.

Graphically the situation will be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFWHa.jpg

How can I proceed to fix this situation ?

Thank you in advance for any kind of help, I've already tried lot of things, I'm really struggling with this problem.

Comment: We can't copy/paste from image. Please provide entire or at least part of your dataframe and the expected output. Mention me with @Drakax when you've updated your question or I won't receive notification ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that this is not the prettiest solution, but at least it works. Assuming that the taller and shorter frames are `f1` and `f2`, respectively, the steps are

1. Create a "fake" frame `f` with the same height as `f1` but with no `cluster` column.
2. Gradually fill `f` at relevant indices taken from `f1` with data from `f2`.
3. Concatenate the (partially filled) `f` with `f1`

To demonstrate this idea, let's say that the two frames are

```
>>> f1
   cluster  day  A  B
0        2    0  1  2
1        2    1  3  4
2        1    2  5  6
3        1    3  7  8

>>> f2
   cluster  day   A   B
0        1    5  10  20
1        1    9  30  40
2        2    6  50  60
```

The code is as follows (where `np` is `numpy`)

```
f = f1.drop('cluster', axis=1).copy()   # the fake frame
f[:] = np.nan
f1g = f1.groupby('cluster')   # Allow for a second indexing way using cluster id
f2g = f2.groupby('cluster')

clusters1 = f1g.groups.keys()
clusters2 = f2g.groups.keys()
for cluster in (clusters1 & clusters2):
    idx1 = f1g.get_group(cluster).index   # indices of entries of the current cluster in f1
    idx2 = f2g.get_group(cluster).index   # indices of entries of the current cluster in f2
    m = len(idx2)
    f.loc[idx1[0:m]] = f2.loc[idx2[0:m], ['day', 'A', 'B']].to_numpy()   # fill the first m entries of current cluster in f with data from f2
```

And the result after concatenating the fake `f` and the taller `f1`

```
>>> pd.concat([f1, f], axis=1)
   cluster  day  A  B  day     A     B
0        2    0  1  2  6.0  50.0  60.0
1        2    1  3  4  NaN   NaN   NaN
2        1    2  5  6  5.0  10.0  20.0
3        1    3  7  8  9.0  30.0  40.0
```

Final note: You can obtain `idx1` and `idx2` in the for loop using ways other than `groupby`, but I think the latter is one of the fastest ways to do this.

Comment: Well not exactly, if I take your example:
f1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,5,6], [1,3,7,8]], columns=['cluster', 'day', 'A', 'B'])
f2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,50,60]], columns=['cluster', 'day', 'A', 'B']) 
(I changed f2)
What I'm looking for is not to merge the same day. What I want is that the first row of f2 bind on the first row of f1 (which is not the case when the days are not the same). I want it to work even if the days are different, that's where the difficulty is @bui

Comment: So you always want the first row of f2 to merge with first row of f1 regardless of cluster and/or day? If that's the case how would the `cluster` and `day` columns of the output look like? I added images to my answer so let me know if it is what you want.

Comment: Regardless of day but not for cluster. Like for each new number of cluster, the first rows of cluster"x" of f2 would match the first rows of cluster"x" of f1. And so, the last rows of each clusters"x" of f2 would be NA values. I hope my explanation are clear. @bui

Comment: But then how would the `day` column of the output look like? Are there two `day` columns in the output (one for the day of `f1` and the other for the day of `f2`)? It would be a great help if you give a concrete example.

Comment: Yep exactly you have then 2 day columns you're right @bui (I can't post screenshots on stack for the moment, I don't have enought points).

Comment: In your image you only show one `day` column in the output so I misunderstood. I will try to update the answer an let you know if I did it.

Comment: I updated my solution. Hope that it's to your expectation.

Comment: Yep it works perfectly for me, ty very much. However there is a little typo that is: f1g.get_group(cluster).index and not f1.get_group(cluster).index

Comment: You're right. I forgot to add the `g` for both `f1g.get_group()` and `f2g.get_group()`.